# Kafka Spark Consumer API Issue with Dependancy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a spark consumer API to receive the data from Kafka.But in my consumer code I am not able to add jar/dependency for these two classes:
import org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverLauncher;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Scheduler;

I am using Kafka 0.11.0.1 and Spark 2.2.0 on my local machine and my Consumer code is :

```
package kafkatest2;

import java.io.Serializable; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2; 
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel; 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration; 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Time; 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream; 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverLauncher;

import consumer.kafka.MessageAndMetadata;
import kafka.consumer.Consumer;

import org.apache.spark.streaming.Scheduler;

//import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
//import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata; 

public class ConsumerTest implements Serializable { 

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 4332618245650072140L; 

 public void start() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, 
   ClassNotFoundException { 

  run(); 
 } 

 private void run() { 

  Properties props = new Properties(); 
  props.put("zookeeper.hosts", "localhost"); 
  props.put("zookeeper.port", "2181"); 
  props.put("zookeeper.broker.path", "/brokers"); 
  props.put("kafka.topic", "test-topic"); 
  props.put("kafka.consumer.id", "test-id"); 
  props.put("zookeeper.consumer.connection", "localhost:2182"); 
  props.put("zookeeper.consumer.path", "/spark-kafka"); 
  // Optional Properties 
  props.put("consumer.forcefromstart", "true"); 
  props.put("consumer.fetchsizebytes", "1048576"); 
  props.put("consumer.fillfreqms", "250"); 
  props.put("consumer.backpressure.enabled", "true"); 

  SparkConf _sparkConf = new SparkConf().set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "false"); 
  JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(_sparkConf, new Duration(1000)); 
  // Specify number of Receivers you need. 
  int numberOfReceivers = 3; 
  JavaDStream<MessageAndMetadata> unionStreams = ReceiverLauncher.launch(jsc, props, numberOfReceivers, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY()); 
  unionStreams 
    .foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaRDD<MessageAndMetadata>, Time, Void>() { 
     @Override 
     public Void call(JavaRDD<MessageAndMetadata> rdd, Time time) throws Exception { 
      rdd.collect(); 
      System.out.println(" Number of records in this batch " 
        + rdd.count()); 

      return null; 
     } 
    }); 

  jsc.start(); 
  jsc.awaitTermination(); 
 } 

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

  ConsumerTest consumer = new ConsumerTest(); 
  consumer.start(); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use maven. Here is a working pom.xml. (Tune the kafka / Spark versions if needed).
Hope this helps.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <!--    
        <scope>provided</scope>
         -->
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```